# map hibernate object with liferay internal table - many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay, hibernate-mapping, liferay-6

i would like to know - if possible - how can i map a hibernate object model to an internal liferay table 'user_'.

My Hibernate Object model is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageviewer_crreviewprotocol")
public class CRReviewProtocol implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "RevProtId")
private Long revProtId;

@Column(name = "RevProtDescription")
private String RevProtDescription;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="imageviewer_revprot_features", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RevProtId")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="VarId")})
private Set<CRVariable> crvariables = new HashSet<CRVariable>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="imageviewer_revprot_patients", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RevProtId")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ImPatientId")})
private Set<CRImageData> crimagedata = new HashSet<CRImageData>();
```

Which builds a main table 'imageviewer_crreviewprotocol' and two other intermediate tables for M-N relations with two other entities.

I would like to have another intermediate M-N table which will store internal (liferay) userId and RevProtId. But how am i going to map this? I have tried code like:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="imageviewer_revprot_reviewers", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RevProtId")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ReviewerId")})
//private Set<BigInteger> userId = new HashSet<BigInteger>(); 
//private Set<User> user = new HashSet<User>();
```

But obviously i am missing something!

Anybody with relevant experience?

Comment: Is there any way to set (import, or set as mapping class) liferay table user_ in hibernate configuration xml file?